# Use a trigger to stop insert to a table not working MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

hi i am using `MySQL` `TRIGGERS` , i am using **MySQL 5.5.8** ,  i have a table . since `MySQL` not allow `CHECK` Constraint , i used a `TRIGGER` to check an input value is wrong , if the input value is wrong i tried to gave a message and stop insert the records to the table . but it ignores my `TRIGGER` , record insert to the table if it contains invalid data .

**table**

```
CREATE TABLE pupil_data
(
PupilID int(10) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
PupilForeName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PupilLastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(1),
DateOfBirth  DATE ,
PhoneNumber int(10) ,
FamilyID int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PupilID),
FOREIGN KEY (FamilyID) REFERENCES family_data(FamilyID)  
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
,
UNIQUE (PhoneNumber)
) ENGINE=innodb;
```

**trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `check_pupil_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `pupil_data`
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN
  IF  CHAR_LENGTH( NEW.DateOfBirth ) < 4 THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'check constraint on pupil_data.DateOfBirth  failed'
    END IF;
END$$  
DELIMITER ;
```

i want to check if the value entered for DateOfBirth is less than 4 characters , then don't insert the record , give an error message but .

[image]

the value of `DateOfBirth` is `0` , so i suppose it should give an error , but as you can see it is executing ignoring it.

what is the reason , i am doing this wrong , please help, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: The insert statement does indicate a warning, did you try `show warnings`?

Comment: While creating `trigger` I think you missed out the `semi colon` on error If check.

Comment: @ranjith , please show me how to do that

Comment: @MikePurcell , but the insertion happens  , can't i stop the insertion ??

Comment: Let change this code. `SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on pupil_data.DateOfBirth  failed';` And check it out.

Comment: @Ranjith , no as Mike mentioned a warning appear , but recoord added to the table

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Can you show the warnings.

Comment: @Ranjith , sse my update , but i think it is not oming from the trigger , but the value of DateOFBirt is truncated issue

Comment: Have you tried raising an exception inside the trigger?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Mostly this issue occurs when the `datatype` mismatch on the column field in db. What is the `datatype` of `DateOfBirth` column.

Comment: a trigger is not the place to do input validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Trigger defination is wrong . You are using date data type and for that you are checking char length . which is probably wrong because mysql by default enters date as '0000-00-00'  Plus your syntax is wrong ...

So your Trigger defination should be like

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `check_pupil_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `pupil_data`
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN
 IF   NEW.DateOfBirth = '0000-00-00' THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on pupil_data.DateOfBirth  failed';
 END IF;
END$$
```

Try this  ..

Comment: :( , it is adding successully even if i gave 0000-00-00 to DateOfBirth

Comment: have you checked the trigger defination... in database ? I am also using this constraint in my database and it works like charm

Comment: how can i check that ???

Comment: Go to information_schema database then run select ACTION_STATEMENT* from TRIGGERS  where TRIGGER_NAME like '%check_pupil_before_insert%'..

Comment: i checked inside  localhost->information_schema->TRIGGERS , but that table has no records :-o

Comment: It means that ur trigger is not created yet .... First confirm that trigger is created.. This trigger defination will surely work .. Well how are you running this sql .. ? if you are running this from GUI of phpadmin then you have to change it a bit ..

Comment: i am running from PhpMyadmin , please help me , how shuld i change this , but when i run the trigger in PHPMyadmin it adds the trigger successfully

Comment: It will not show any error but your trigger is not created until you have successful trigger creation message .. ok now I am changing my answer .. rum that query in phpmyadmin .. But before that change delimeter in delimeter box (below sql query box) to $$ .

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Are you able to create Trigger .. ?

Comment: mm no still the same problem

Comment: +1 for fixing, personally I don't like implementing triggers, they add a level of complexity which should be handled at the app layer.